# Why does this statement cause an error in one function but not in another in C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, iso

Statement ***p++ = *source++;** in the following first program doesn't cause any errors but causes the error *ISO C++ forbids cast to non-reference type used as lvalue* in the second program when compiled. Why does this happens?

- The first program

  ```
  #include 

  char *my_strcpy(char *destination, char *source)
  {
      char *p = destination;
      while (*source != '\0')
      {
          *p++ = *source++;
      }
      *p = '\0'; 
      return destination;
  }

  int main()
  {
      char source[] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes";
      char destination[80];   
      my_strcpy(destination, source);
      puts(destination);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- The second program

  ```
  #include 

  char source[] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes";
  char destination[80];

  int main()
  {
      char *p = destination;
      putchar('\n'); 
      while(*source != '\0') 
      {
          *p++ = *source++; 
      }
      *p = '\0';
      puts(destination);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: In the second, `source` is an array. So `source++` is illegal. In the first, what is passed to the function is `&source[0]`, so the function has a pointer which it can increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your first program increments a pointer, while in the second program you apply the `++` operator to an array. Although arrays often behave like pointers, they are *not* pointers. Arrays support pointer arithmetics, but they do not support pointer operators that treat them as `lvalue` (i.e. attempt to modify where they point).

Fixing the problem is trivial - simply create a pointer that points to the array, and use that pointer in your loop, like this:

```
char *p = destination;
putchar('\n'); 
char *src = source;
while(*src != '\0') 
{
    *p++ = *src++; 
}
*p = '\0';
puts(destination);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first program `source` was converted to a pointer to char by passing it to `my_strcpy`, so you could increment it. In the second program, on the other hand, `source` remains an array, and you can't increment an array.

By the way, I think the C library implements `strcpy` in a very short manner, like so:

```
while((*dst++ = *src++));
```

And that's all

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify source, you have create a local pointer to it like you did with p for destination.  source is a staticly defined array so you can only change its contents, not its address.